# Generating Balls for Android Game

Tags: android

I am making a game in Android where i am generating random number for different colored balls. Currently i am generating buttons dynamically and settings the background resource.

I am using some high resolution icons as images. However when they render on screen, all of them gets slightly pixelated and don't look good on screen. I tried it with different sizes of icons but it was of no use.

Can anyone suggest where i can be going wrong and what can be the best way to take care of these things. I am new to game programming so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this isnt an answer to you queston, but have you considered using AndEngine as the engine to your game? It does the job exceptionally well. http://www.andengine.org

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your application is not running at your phone's maximum resolution. You need to specify the target version of Android in your manifest file, otherwise the app defaults to an early version and only runs at low-res.

If your phone supports Android 2.2 (Froyo) then try adding this line to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Be sure to put it in the manifest section, not the application section. If you see a line for "android:versionName" then put it immediately after that line.

If your phone doesn't support Android 2.2 then change the minSdkVersion number to 7. If it's an older version then go down to 6 or 5. You'll need to make sure you have the correct SDK files installed on your development machine. (ie: you won't be able to compile an Android 2.2 app if you only have the 2.1 SDK installed.)

Comment: I have specified the minSDKVersion in the manifest file. Trouble is that the image is getting scaled up and down based on different mobile handsets resolution. Putting all my images under drawable-nodpi displays the images perfectly but the layout is disturbed. I would like to know any way of displaying images perfectly. And it should also work with different mobile layouts.